# Database includes images, can't call these images from the Database (Android Application)

Tags: java, android, database, image, sqlite

So I've created a database which contains an ID, Name and Bitmap picture associated with each entry to the database. The database inputs look like so:

```
package com.finalyearproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ChordImages extends Activity {
 private MySQLiteHelper DbHelper;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.chordview);

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords A7th = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a_7), "A-7th");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords A_Maj = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a_maj), "Chord: A-Major");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords A_Min = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a_min), "Chord: A-Minor");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords B_7th = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.b_7), "Chord: B-7th");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords C_7th = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.c_7), "Chord: C-7th");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords C_Maj = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.c_maj), "Chord: C-Major");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords D_7th = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.d_7), "Chord: D-7th");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords D_Maj = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.d_maj), "Chord: D-Major");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords D_Min = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.d_min), "Chord: D-Minor");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords E_7th = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.e_7), "Chord: E-7th");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords E_Maj = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.e_maj), "Chord: E-Major");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords E_Min = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.e_min), "Chord: E-Minor");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords F_Maj = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.f_maj), "Chord: F-Major");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords G_7th = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.g_7), "Chord: G-7th");

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords G_Maj = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.g_maj), "Chord: G-Major");


      DbHelper.open();
      DbHelper.insertCrdDetails(A7th);
      DbHelper.close();
      A7th = null;
      DbHelper.open();
      A7th = DbHelper.retriveCrdDetails();
      DbHelper.close();

  TextView crdname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
  crdname.setText(A7th.getName());

  ImageView crdphoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);
  crdphoto.setImageBitmap(A7th.getBitmap());
  }
}
```

Basically the last section here I want it to find the 'name' TextView on my UI and assign it the value of the 'A7th' name from the Database and the code that follows is to also grab the corresponding image. I also have another couple of Java files that may help with detecting why my image isn't appearing.

Chords.java:

```
package com.finalyearproject;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class Chords {

    private int id;
    private String chord;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public Chords(){}

    public Chords(Bitmap picture, String chord) {
        super();
        this.chord = chord;
        this.bitmap = picture;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Chords [id=" + id + ", chord=" + chord + ", picture=" + bitmap + "]";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "Chord Name: " + chord;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

This contains the 2 methods that should be getting the names and images associated with each entry. I think this part is working Ok.

MySQLiteHelper.java:

```
package com.finalyearproject;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MySQLiteHelper {

    public static final String CRD_ID = "id";
    public static final String CRD_NAME = "name";
    public static final String CRD_PHOTO = "photo";

    private DatabaseHelper mMySQLiteHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ChordDB.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String CHORD_TABLE = "Chords";

    private static final String CREATE_CHORD_TABLE = "create table "
            + CHORD_TABLE + " (" + CRD_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + CRD_PHOTO
            + " blob not null, " + CRD_NAME + " text not null );";


    private final Context mCtx;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(CREATE_CHORD_TABLE);
  }

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CHORD_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
  }
 }

public void Reset() {

    mMySQLiteHelper.onUpgrade(this.mDb, 1, 1);
 }

public MySQLiteHelper(Context ctx) {

      mCtx = ctx;
      mMySQLiteHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
 }

public MySQLiteHelper open() throws SQLException {

    mDb = mMySQLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
 }

public void close() {

    mMySQLiteHelper.close();
 }

public void insertCrdDetails(Chords chord) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(CRD_PHOTO, Utility.getBytes(chord.getBitmap()));
    cv.put(CRD_NAME, chord.getName());
    mDb.insert(CHORD_TABLE, null, cv);
 }

public Chords retriveCrdDetails() throws SQLException {

    Cursor cur = mDb.query(true, CHORD_TABLE, new String[] { CRD_PHOTO, CRD_NAME }, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            byte[] blob = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(CRD_PHOTO));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CRD_NAME));
            cur.close();

            return new Chords(Utility.getPhoto(blob), name);
  }
        cur.close();
        return null;
 }
}
```

This is the file that creates the database I believe and it works in association with my Utility.java file which changes the images to a ByteArray before changing them back at the point they're called upon. The Utility file is below

Utility.java:

```
package com.finalyearproject;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class Utility {
 // convert from bitmap to byte array
    public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) 
        {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
            return stream.toByteArray();
        }

  // convert from byte array to bitmap
 public static Bitmap getPhoto(byte[] image) {

     return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
    }
}
```

I have each of the images in question saved to my Drawable folder and each given a unique name, but when I open the ChordImages.java activity within the application itself it's not displaying the image to the first image. I would like to have just one image displaying for now and then I'm going to work on using a Spinner to let me change which image is actually going to display, can anyone see any blatent issues with my code that would prevent the image from loading. I'll attach the LogCat error log below:

LogCat:

```
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013): Error inserting photo=[B@4241ffc8 name=Chord Name: A-7th
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column name is not unique (code 19)
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:905)
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013):    at com.finalyearproject.MySQLiteHelper.insertCrdDetails(MySQLiteHelper.java:77)
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013):    at com.finalyearproject.ChordImages.onCreate(ChordImages.java:63)
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
04-03 13:51:28.401: E/SQLiteDatabase(24013):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 13:51:28.706: E/SpannableStringBuilder(24013): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-03 13:51:28.706: E/SpannableStringBuilder(24013): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

I can see the 'Error inserting photo' message in the LogCat files but I can't seem to decipher what's causing the issue! Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Still going for saving the images in the DB then? ;) Only thing I can suggest as far as your error is concerned is goto Settings -> Apps and find your app. Force close it and then delete the data - that will make sure the DB is recreated from scratch. If that doesn't work then I'm not sure what the issue is. You do have some very strange approaches to coding though - creating a new helper with `DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);` before each time you create a new `Chords` instance.

Comment: @Squonk Ill give that a go and see what happens, If I can get the image to display then I'll have a go at linking it with the Spinner... I probably have an obscure approach to coding because I'm a beginner at Android Development!

Comment: Ok I managed to get the Database stuff sorted and an Image appearing, I also now have a spinner that changes the text based on what's been selected... I think I'll post in a new question for assistance with that! You're comments helped me lookin the right places @Squonk thanks alot bud!